# typeerror message when trying to remove a property from a selected data structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, typeerror

I am getting a type error message when I am trying to remove a 
   property from a data structure I have created everytime I click to remove 
   a property it throws this error code " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read 
    property 'map' of undefined
    at Object.deleteItem (app.js:69)
    at HTMLDivElement.ctrlDeleteIitem (app.js:292)
   deleteItem @ app.js:69
    ctrlDeleteIitem @ app.js:292"

I am following a JS tutorial and i am currently building a budget app but 
   I am getting this error message and I am unsure as to why as I believe I 
   have declared all the relevant variables but I clearly haven't.

I have added comments specifically like this "<-- problem line of code" 
   and "<-- end of problem code ->" so you can clearly see where the issue is 
   occurring

I have tried already to add parsentInt method to line 288 to contvert the 
  string into a number but still I am being told that I have not defined map 
   at line 69

```
 //budget controller 

//function constructor
var budgetController = (function() {

var Expense = function(id,description, value) {
this.id = id,
this.description = description,
this.value = value;
};

var income = function(id,description, value) {
    this.id = id,
    this.description = description,
    this.value = value;
};

  var totalCal= function (type){
    var sum = 0;

    data.items[type].forEach(function(current){
      sum += current.value;
    });
    data.total[type] = sum;
}

var data = {
    items: {
        exp: [],
        inc:[]
  },
  total: {
exp: 0,
inc: 0
   },
  budget:0,
   percentage: -1

  };

     return{
      addItem(type,des,val){

        var newItem, ID;


        // create new ID 
        if (data.items[type].length > 0){
        ID = data.items[type][data.items[type].length -1].id + 1;
        } else {
            ID = 0;
        }

        // Create new item based on inc or exp type
        if (type === 'exp'){
        newItem = new Expense(ID,des,val);
        } else if (type === 'inc'){
            newItem = new income(ID, des, val);
        }
        // Push it into data structure 
        data.items[type].push(newItem);
        // Return the new element
        return newItem;
    },

  <-- this block of code is generating the error-->     deleteItem: 
               function (type, id) {
        var ids, index;

    ids = data.items[type].map(function(current) {

        return current.id;
});
    index = ids.indexOf(id);

    if (index !== -1){
        data.items[type].splice(index, 1);
    }

    },
    <---end of problem code--->
    calculateBudget: function (){

        // calculate total income and expenses
        totalCal('exp');
        totalCal('inc');

        // calculate the budget: income - expenses 
        data.budget = data.total.inc - data.total.exp;




        //calculate the percentage of income that we spend

        if (data.total.inc > 0) {
            data.percentage = Math.round((data.total.exp / 
      data.total.inc) *100);
        } else {
            data.percentage = -1;
        }





    },

    getBudget: function () {
        return  {
            budget: data.budget,
            income: data.total.inc,
            Expense:data.total.exp,
            percentage: data.percentage
        };

    },

    testing: function(){
        console.log(data);
    }
   };



    })();



      //UI controller 
     var UIController = (function() {
//public function

// private object to store strings to make code more cleaner
var DOMstrings = {
    inputType: '.expType',
    inputDescription: '.expDescription',
    inputValue:'.expValue',
    inputBtn: '.plus__btn',
    incomeContainer: '.incomeList',
    expensesContainer: '.expensesList',
    budgetLabel: '.budgetValue',
    incomeLabel: '.budgetIncomeValue',
    expensesLabel:'.budgetExpensesValue',
    percentageLabel:'.budgetExpensesPercentage',
    container: '.container'
};


return {
    getInput: function () {
        return {
    type: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputType).value, // 
    will be either inc or exp
    description: 
    document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputDescription).value,
    value: parseFloat 
    (document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputValue).value)
    };
   },

     addListItems: function (obj, type){
    var html, newHTML, element;
    // Create HTML string with placeholder text 

    if (type === 'inc'){
        element = DOMstrings.incomeContainer;
    html = '<div class="item clearfix" id="%inc-%"><div 
   class="item__description">%description%</div><div class="right 
   clearfix"> <div class="item__value">%value%</div><div 
   class="item__delete"><button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion- 
   ios-close-outline"></i></button></div></div></div>';
    } else if (type === 'exp'){
        element = DOMstrings.expensesContainer;
    html='<div class="item clearfix" id="exp-%id%"><div 
  class="item__description">%description%</div><div class="right 
  clearfix"><div class="item__value">%value%</div><div 
  class="item__percentage">21%</div><div class="item__delete"><button 
  class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i> 
  </button> 
  </div></div></div>';
    }

    //replace the placeholder text with some actual data

    newHTML = html.replace('%id%', obj.id);
    newHTML = newHTML.replace('%description%', obj.description);
    newHTML = newHTML.replace('%value%', obj.value);

    // insert HTML into DOM


   document.querySelector(element).insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', 
   newHTML);

},

// method to clear input fields after user types in a value and 
  presses enter
clearFields: function (){
    var fields, fieldsArr;

    fields = document.querySelectorAll(DOMstrings.inputDescription 
   + ', ' + DOMstrings.inputValue);

    fieldsArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(fields);

    fieldsArr.forEach(function(current, index, array){
      current.value = "";

    });
    // this line of code ensures after the users presses enter the 
    input field goes back to the first.
      fieldsArr[0].focus();
     },



   seeBudget: function(obj) {
    document.querySelector(DOMstrings.budgetLabel).textContent = 
   obj.budget;
    document.querySelector(DOMstrings.incomeLabel).textContent = 
    obj.income;
    document.querySelector(DOMstrings.expensesLabel).textContent = 
   obj.Expense;
    document.querySelector(DOMstrings.percentageLabel).textContent 
  = obj.percentage;

    if(obj.percentage >0) {

   document.querySelector(DOMstrings.percentageLabel).textContent = 
   obj.percentage + '%';
    } else {

     document.querySelector(DOMstrings.percentageLabel).textContent = '-- 
  --';

    }
  },
  //exposing private object so I can pass this to an given module
   getDomstrings: function(){
    return DOMstrings;
   },
    };

   })();

  //Global app controller 
  var appController = (function(budgetCtrl,UICtrl) {

// function for all event listeners
var eventListeners = function () {

var DOM = UICtrl.getDomstrings();   
document.querySelector(DOM.inputBtn).addEventListener('click', 
  addItem);  
  document.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
   if (e.keyCode === 13 || e.which === 13) {
  addItem();
     }
 });
 document.querySelector(DOM.container).addEventListener('click', 
 ctrlDeleteIitem);
  };

       var budgetUpdate = function(){
       //5. calculate the budget 
    budgetCtrl.calculateBudget();


    //6. return the budget

    var budget = budgetCtrl.getBudget();


    //7. display the budget on the UI

    UICtrl.seeBudget(budget);
      }

var addItem = function(){
    var input, newItem;

    //1. get the filed input data
    input = UICtrl.getInput();

    if (input.description !== "" && !isNaN(input.value)  && 
   input.value > 0){
  //2. add the item to the the budget controller

  newItem = budgetCtrl.addItem(input.type,input.description,input.value);

 //3. add the item to the UI 
 UICtrl.addListItems(newItem, input.type)

  //4. clear input fields
 UICtrl.clearFields();

 //5 calculate and update budget
 budgetUpdate();


    }




};

var ctrlDeleteIitem = function (e) {

var elementID, splitID, type, ID;
    elementID = 
   (e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id);
              <-- problem block of code -->
    if(elementID){

        splitID = elementID.split('-');
        type = splitID[0];
        ID = parseInt(splitID[1]);


        //1 delete the item from the data structure.
          budgetCtrl.deleteItem(type, ID);
        //2 delete the item from the UI
          <-- end of problem code--->
        //3 Update and show the new budget

    }

   }

   return {
    init: function() {
        console.log('App has started');
        UICtrl.seeBudget({budget: 0,
            income: 0 ,
            Expense:0,
            percentage: -1
        });
        eventListeners();
    }
   };


  })(budgetController, UIController);
  // line to run event listener function
  appController.init();


 expected result is for there not to be an error message and for i.e. if 
 I was to input test 1 with a value of 12 into my budget app when I click 
the button to remove it from my app it should be removed from my data 
structure first. thanks in advance.
```

Comment: "*but still I am being told that I have not defined map at line 69*" no, the message says that you are *calling* `map` on `undefined`. So in `data.items[type].map()` the part *before* the `.map` call is `data.items[type]` and that resolves as `undefined`.

Comment: Hey @VLAZ thanks for this  just wanted to clarify exactly what you are saying I should call just  data.items[type] by its self? if not could you show me how to implement this via code? I am still learning JS on a deeper level so im not trying to be difficult I just want to see exactly how it should be implemented based on what you have said. thanks

Comment: `data.items[type]` resolves as `undefined` in that code. You need to find out why - the best way is to step through with a debugger and/or log some values. See what `type` is, since it most likely isn't a key that exists in `this,items` *or` if `type` should exist, then `this.items` exists, then it doesn't have the key.